# Cannot ssh or ping to linux server from local windows machine, but server can definitely be reached from other devices

Tags: linux, ssh

The Problem is the following: I could previously access the Linux Server via ssh without a problem on my local Windows10 machine. I was running a program that could possibly have crashed due to high cpu/Memory usage, and a few days later I could not reach the server anymore. (Error message: Connection timed out)

Since I could also not reach the server from another machine, I tried rebooting the server. I still could not access the server via my local machine (could also not ping it), I could however remote into a different Server via my local machine, and from there access the Linux server. So I know the server can currently be reached via ssh.

I also still can access other servers via ssh on my local machine, so it should also not be an issue with my ssh. I originally could reach the server only in a VPN. To my knowledge, nothing in my or the servers settings has changed. What I have tried so far:

- Running it without Firewall/Antivirus in case it was suddenly blocking sth
- Rebooting a second time
- I previously used GitBash, tried again with CygWin and Windows Power Shell

All to no avail, and I have run out of ideas what else to try or what to google. Any more suggestion as to how I could troubleshoot further?

Comment: You should check that your network topology has not changed, and therefore check that the server indeed is accessible from the local machine.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include your network setup? Can you try to connect to your server directly with an ethernet cable?

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion and sorry to reply so late. Yes, you were right, for some reason the server cannot connect to the Internet. It did not occur to me to check that because it was reachable from the other server, but they turned out to be directly connected. Now I at least know where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: You're welcome. Good job. I'm sure you can solve this.